# How to get last selectedindex

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I need to get the **last** selected value from a dropdown control. But I get wrong information.

I need this kind of control to allow users to select every option they want. But I've to validate every option they select after getting the selectedvalue.

I've deployed an ASP.NET dropdown control in a webform. It's databinded in server side, and the resulting hmtl is the following:

```
<select name="ddl" id="ddl" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1800346</option>
    <option value="2">1800353</option>
    <option value="3">1800358</option>
    <option value="4">1800509</option>
    <option value="5">1800514</option>
</select>
```

And this is my jQuery code: It alerts the selectedIndex and the selected text.

```
$("#ddl").on("change", function () {
    alert($("#ddl")[0].selectedIndex);
    alert($("#ddl option:selected").text());
});
```

With `alert($("#ddl")[0].selectedIndex)` I get the first selected index. For example, if you click on the first checkbox, you'll get "1" the first time. After that, if you click on the third checkbox you'll get "1" again (instead of "3"). Because the first option is selected.

I also tried with `alert($("#ddl option:selected").text())` but I get everything.

Is there any way to get only the last selected value? I'm only able to get the first selected index.

You can find my code also here: http://jsfiddle.net/bDvkQ/342/

Any help will be very welcome,

Regards,

Comment: you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bDvkQ/343/ selected option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for this code

```
$("#ddl").on("change", function () {
var lastText = "";
var last = 0;
$("#ddl option:selected").each(function () {
   lastText = this.text;
    last = this.value;
});
alert(lastText);
alert(last);
});
```

and you can find from this link to http://jsfiddle.net/bDvkQ/344/

Comment: this works for me with the following update: $("#ddl").on("change", function () {
  var lastText = "";
  var last = 0;
  if ($("#ddl")[0].selectedIndex > 0) {
   $("#ddl option:selected").each(function () {
    lastText = this.text;
    last = this.value;
   });
   alert(lastText);
   alert(last);
  }
 }); Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think it wasn't clear for you.

When you click on the ddl, it will choose the selected value. Just return it.

Do something like this:

```
$("#ddl").on("change", function () {
alert($("#ddl").val());
alert($("#ddl option:selected").text());
});
```

It works well for me.
Hope this helped.

Comment: I cannot use this script because it shows all vals, not the last one. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we can select the last selected value (and first one),

```
      $("#ddl").on("change", function () {  
      var selValues = $("#ddl").val();
        alert(selValues[0]);
      alert(selValues[selValues.length - 1]);
    });
```

However, if user starts selecting values in the reverse direction (from bottom), you will not get the last selected/clicked value but you will always get the selected value that comes last in the dropdown.

I would suggest to create another function/handler that gets all the selected values and validates them one by one rather than doing validation on every single click/selection of this multi select control.

Comment: I cannot use this script because it shows all vals, not the last one. Thanks anyway

Comment: I think that is not correct. I have tested this script on IE9 and IE10. Which browser are you using?

Actually, val() will return all the selected items but then we are fetching the last item from the array.